# Request headers "Content-Length" and "Host" missing from request header in flutter web production build

Tags: flutter, dart, cors

I am trying to deploy my flutter project on the web but the request header to make my api requests successful and missing from the request headers and this happens only in production.

Attached below are the send headers when running the flutter project in debug mode on local browser

[image]

But when i make the release build in both html and canvaskit i get the following headers for every request, this happens when i use release build with localhost or on my web hosting.

[image]

This causes all my api requests to fail in production but work in debug mode. I have already tried adding the required header manually but chrome "refuses to add unsafe headers"

The server requires that "Content-Length" and "Host" headers be set.

Comment: Can you check console in browser for logs for the url that you are facing iussue ?

Comment: I have checked the server just sent an error back due to the missing header

i tried using postman with the exact same headers that flutter sent and i get the same error 400 or 500 error

Comment: Please show the code that's generating the HTTP message.  ALSO: compare your code with this example: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data

Answer (score 0):

After some more research we discovered the problem was not with flutter at all  but with cors and the backend, for cross site api access the browser usually makes a preflight OPTIONS request to verify if access was authorised but our backend did not handle that request.